# Error while integrating firebase in react-native. No Virtual method getLanguageCode()Ljava/lang/String in class LCom/google/firebase/auth/FireBaseAuth

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, firebase, react-native

I'm getting this error when im integrating firebase in reactnative.

[image]

AppName/android/app/build.gradle

```
        dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
    // compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.0"

    compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

AppName/android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

AppName/android/settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
```

i followed https://codeburst.io/react-native-app-with-facebook-sdk-login-and-firebase-storage-606744701207.

Answer (score 0):

please use gradle version as follows its work for me:

```
dependencies {
compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}
compile project(':react-native-facebook-login')

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1"  // From node_modules

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```